# ImportError: cannot import name JSONClient

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-ml

Whenever I request to GoogleVision api's, this error pops up. Even cannot install/uninstall any of the package

Sample Output:

```
engineer@engineer:~$ sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

[sudo] password for engineer: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2091, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3036, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3064, in _initialize_master_working_set
    for dist in working_set
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3064, in <genexpr>
    for dist in working_set
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2594, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2162, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/engineer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/logging/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.logging.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/logging/client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from google.cloud.client import JSONClient
```

ImportError: cannot import name JSONClient

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3322

Comment: Happy to engage you here or on GitHub @Nayeem. The `pip` error stack trace isn't that useful. More useful would be to run "pip show google-cloud google-cloud-core google-cloud-vision"

Comment: Additionally: Ensure pip is up to date (`pip install --upgrade pip`)

Comment: Thanks @rhaertel80, due to package issue it got corrupted, reinstalled everything, working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue today with 0.24.0 version,
I have downgraded google-cloud to 0.23.0 for now,
pip install --upgrade google-cloud==0.23.0
its working

Comment: In my case, pip was itself not working, for anything and everything it was giving that JSONClient Error

Comment: upgrade pip if its not at latest version